# Problema Eclipse al usar la tecla Control + tecla se cuelga

Tags: java, jsp, eclipse, tomcat, ide

Uso Eclipse para Java y muchas veces cuando le doy a la tecla Control + otra, se cuelga y un buen rato i si hago lo mismo pero con el ratón no suele pasar. También se cuelga a veces al simplemente seleccionar una palabra o liena de código. Muchas veces le doy a "File" y se queda colgado bastante rato en cambio con el resto de opciones del menú de arriba se despliegan sin problema.
Me pasa tanto si estoy conectado al Tomcat como si no.
¿Alguna idea?
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

He visto que desactivando el Hiperlinking o cambiándolo de tecla (por defecto está en la tecla control y mientras copiaba, pegaba etc estaba haciendo hiperlinking) ya no me pasa. Pero tampoco es la solución, ya que cuando lo uso con otra tecla sigue colgándose.
Sigue colgándose a veces al darle al desplegable "file".

Answer (score 0):

Buenas a mi me pasaba algo parecido yendo a:

**Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys**

Y restaurando por defecto cada boton se soluciono.

Espero que te ayude

Comment: Nada, la tecla que tengo asignada a hiperlinking sigue colgándome el pc. Gracias de todas formas.